# Bluetooth Tethering issue Galaxy S4 to Samsung Note 10

Tags: tethering, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

Hi I tried to tether from my S4 to my Note 10.1, via bluetooth, even though I am able to pair both, on the galaxy note 10.1 it says No Internet Connection.

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: It would be good if you could tell us what method you're trying to use for bluetooth thethering. Tell us the steps that you're taking on the devices when you try.

Comment: Plus: which device acts as the access point, which as the client?

Comment: on the S4 (Access point): Settings->network connections->more connections-> Tethering -> check the box for "Bluetooth tethering"

Comment: Can you add to your question what version of android are on each of the phones and if your phone is rooted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 3 things, to get a running bluetooth tethered connection:

1. Pair both devices as usual and enable Bluetooth on each
2. Enable BT-tethering on the access point device (needs to be set each reboot):
   Settings -> Wireless & Networks -> More..-> Tethering -> Enable Bluetooth tethering`
3. Activate Bluetooth tethering on the client device: 
   `Settings->Bluetooth->"John's Phone"-> Options"-> enable "Internet access"`

If it doesn't work the first time, switch off/on Bluetooth on both devices and retry.

These are the steps as I use them to tether my Nexus 10 to my Google Galaxy Nexus.

PS: If you don't like to manually enable BT tethering each reboot, use [Bluetooth Auto Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.refluxa.android.bat) to have it enabled automatically during boot.

Comment: So, I also forgot to mention couple of points: I am able to connect through tether to the internet (IF MY PHONE IS CONNECTED THROUGH WIFI), but I can't connect to the internet on the Galaxy Note 10.1 if my phone is connected just through my Data plan.

Comment: OK, got it. Seems like a routing issue in the network stack, strange behaviour. Have you tried switching on/off/on wifi during an existing bluetooth tether connection? My Galaxy Nexus allows that, it just "works" and routes traffic over whatever connection is primary at the moment (wifi or data plan). However, sometimes it doesn't work right at first and I have to disable/re-enable bluetooth on both devices before it connects.